# Conditional filling of radial chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can calculate the negative and positive area, and crossing points when I want to draw two columns, i.e. VALUE1 and VALUE2, from same array(rawdata2).

```js
rawdata = [   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 102,     "VALUE2": 118,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 20   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 110,     "VALUE2": 95,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 20   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:40:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 153,     "VALUE2": 117,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 40   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-10-31T23:40:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 125,     "VALUE2": 98,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 40   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 112,     "VALUE2": 117,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 60   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 120,     "VALUE2": 100,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 60   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 147,     "VALUE2": 108,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 260   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T03:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 130,     "VALUE2": 98,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 260   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:30:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 152,     "VALUE2": 111,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 450   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T06:30:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 140,     "VALUE2": 101,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 450   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 112,     "VALUE2": 101,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 540   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T08:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 120,     "VALUE2": 90,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 540   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T11:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 122,     "VALUE2": 100,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 720   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T11:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 130,     "VALUE2": 95,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 720   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T15:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 112,     "VALUE2": 101,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 960   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T15:00:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 125,     "VALUE2": 98,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 960   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T17:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 147,     "VALUE2": 108,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 1100   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T17:20:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 129,     "VALUE2": 102,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 1100   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T20:59:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 151,     "VALUE2": 102,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 1,     "minuteTime": 1319   },   {     "DATE_TIME": "2018-11-01T20:59:00.000Z",     "VALUE1": 132,     "VALUE2": 90,     "INSPECTION": 1,     "STATE": 0,     "minuteTime": 1319   } ]
const width = 954;
const height = width;
const margin = 5;
const innerRadius = width / 10;
const outerRadius = width / 4 - margin;



          function checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
        // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
        var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
            x: null,
            y: null,
            onLine1: false,
            onLine2: false
        };
        denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
        if (denominator === 0) {
            return result;
        }
        a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
        b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
        numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
        numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
        a = numerator1 / denominator;
        b = numerator2 / denominator;

        // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
        result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
        result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
        /*
                // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
                x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
                y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));
                */
        // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
        if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
            result.onLine1 = true;
        }
        // if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
        if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
            result.onLine2 = true;
        }
        // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
        return result;
    }
// const width = 954;
// const height = width;
// const margin = 10;
// const innerRadius = width / 5;
// const outerRadius = width / 2 - margin;



      let rawdata2 = rawdata.filter(d => d.INSPECTION == 1);

      const minuteScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // 0 to 23:59 (24 hours * 60 minutes without -1 or else change to 1439 //- 1)
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

      const minuteTimeValues = rawdata2.map(d => d.minuteTime);

      const x = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([0, 1439]) // Set the domain using the extent of the "minuteTime" values
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]); // Set the desired range

      //console.log(rawdata)

      const minValue1 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const minValue2 = d3.min(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);
      const maxValue1 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE1);
      const maxValue2 = d3.max(rawdata, d => d.VALUE2);

      const yMin = minValue1 < minValue2 ? minValue1 : minValue2;
      const yMax = maxValue1 > maxValue2 ? maxValue1 : maxValue2;

      const y = d3.scaleLinear()
                  .domain([yMin, yMax])
                  .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]);

// Modify the xAxis generator to display only the hour and add padding

const xAxis = (g) => g
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", 7)
  .call((g) => g.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.range(0, 24)) // create an array of hour values
    .join("g")
      .each((d, i) => d.id = `hour-${i}`)
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.2)
          .attr("d", (d) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), innerRadius)}
            L${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), outerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("path")
          .attr("id", (d) => `hour-${d}`)
          .datum((d) => [d * 60, (d + 1) * 60])
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .attr("d", ([a, b]) => `
            M${d3.pointRadial(x(a), innerRadius-10)}
            A${innerRadius},${innerRadius} 0,0,1 ${d3.pointRadial(x(b), innerRadius)}
          `))
      .call((g) => g.append("text")
        .append("textPath")
          .attr("startOffset", 6)
          .attr("href", (d) => `#hour-${d}`)
          .text((d) => d.toString().padStart(2, "0"))
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
          .attr("transform", (d) => {
            const angle = x(d * 60);
            const radius = innerRadius - 20; // reduce the radius to move the labels closer to the center
                        return `translate(${d3.pointRadial(x(d * 60), radius)})`;
          })
      )
  );



      const yAxis = g => g
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("font-size", 7)
        .call(g => g.selectAll("g")
          .data(y.ticks().reverse())
          .join("g")
          .attr("fill", "none")
          .call(g => g.append("circle")
            .attr("stroke", "#000")
            .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.1)
            .attr("r", y))
          .call(g => g.append("text")
            .attr("y", d => -y(d))
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .attr("stroke", "#fff")
            .attr("stroke-width", 5)
                  .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
            .text((x, i) => `${x.toFixed(0)}${i ? "" : ""}`)
          .clone(true)
            .attr("y", d => y(d))
          .selectAll(function() { return [this, this.previousSibling]; })
          .clone(true)
            .attr("fill", "currentColor")
            .attr("stroke", "none")));

      const line = d3.lineRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime));

      const area = d3.areaRadial()
                    .curve(d3.curveLinear)
                    .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))

      const svg = d3.create("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round");

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "red")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("d", line
          .radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))
          (rawdata2));

      svg.append("path")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("d", line
          .radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))
          (rawdata2));
// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ calc crossing points ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
function findCrossingPoints(data) {
  const crossingPoints = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    const d1 = data[i - 1];
    const d2 = data[i];

    if ((d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2) * (d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) < 0) {
      // There's a crossing point between the two data points
      const t = (0 - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2)) / ((d2.VALUE1 - d2.VALUE2) - (d1.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE2));
      const crossingValue1 = d1.VALUE1 + t * (d2.VALUE1 - d1.VALUE1);
      const crossingValue2 = d1.VALUE2 + t * (d2.VALUE2 - d1.VALUE2);
      crossingPoints.push({ VALUE1: crossingValue1, VALUE2: crossingValue2 });
    }
  }

  return crossingPoints;
}

const crossingPoints = findCrossingPoints(rawdata2);
   function getX(d) {
        return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[1]);
    }
    function getY(d) {
        return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE1))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[2]);
    }
    function getX2(d) {
        return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[1]);
    }
    function getY2(d) {
        return Number(line.radius(d => y(d.VALUE2))([d]).match('M(-?[0-9.]*),(-?[0-9.]*)')[2]);
    }






// +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



// separate data in positive and negative value
let separated = rawdata2.reduce((a, b,index) => {
    let sub = b.VALUE1 - b.VALUE2;
    if (sub > 0) {
        return {positive: [...a.positive, {...b,index}], negative: [...a.negative]};
    }
    return {positive: [...a.positive], negative: [...a.negative, {...b,index}]};

}, {positive: [], negative: []})

let positiveSets = [];

let previous = undefined

separated.positive.forEach((e)=>{
    //if not contiguous
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        // create a new set
        positiveSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        // append value to previous set
        positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1] = [...positiveSets[positiveSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})
//same for negatives
let negativeSets = [];
previous = undefined
separated.negative.forEach((e)=>{
    if (!previous || previous.index + 1 !== e.index) {
        negativeSets.push([e]);
    } else {
        negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1] = [...negativeSets[negativeSets.length - 1], e]
    }
    previous = e;
})

    negativeSets =negativeSets.map(s=>{

        let first = s[0];
        let last = s[s.length-1];
        let next;
        let prev;
        if (first.index > 0){
             prev = rawdata2[first.index-1]
        }else{

             prev = rawdata2[rawdata2.length-1]
        }
        if(last.index === rawdata2.length-1){
            next = rawdata2[0];
        }else{
            next = rawdata2[last.index +1];
        }


        let w = checkLineIntersection(getX(prev),getY(prev),getX(first),getY(first),getX2(prev),getY2(prev),getX2(first),getY2(first))
        let n = checkLineIntersection(getX(last),getY(last),getX(next),getY(next),getX2(last),getY2(last),getX2(next),getY2(next))

        return [{x1:w.x,y1:w.y,x2:w.x,y2:w.y},...s.map(w=>({x1:getX(w),y1:getY(w),x2:getX2(w),y2:getY2(w)})),{x1:n.x,y1:n.y,x2:n.x,y2:n.y}]

    })

    positiveSets =positiveSets.map(s=>{

        let first = s[0];
        let last = s[s.length-1];
        let next;
        let prev;
        if (first.index > 0){
            prev = rawdata2[first.index-1]
        }else{

            prev = rawdata2[rawdata2.length-1]
        }
        if(last.index === rawdata2.length-1){
            next = rawdata2[0];
        }else{
            next = rawdata2[last.index +1];
        }


        let w = checkLineIntersection(getX(prev),getY(prev),getX(first),getY(first),getX2(prev),getY2(prev),getX2(first),getY2(first))
        let n = checkLineIntersection(getX(last),getY(last),getX(next),getY(next),getX2(last),getY2(last),getX2(next),getY2(next))

        return [{x1:w.x,y1:w.y,x2:w.x,y2:w.y},...s.map(w=>({x1:getX(w),y1:getY(w),x2:getX2(w),y2:getY2(w)})),{x1:n.x,y1:n.y,x2:n.x,y2:n.y}]

    })
  const negG = svg.selectAll('.negative').data(negativeSets)
    negG.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class','negative') // "negative" color
        .attr('fill','lightblue')
        .attr("d", (d)=>d3.area().x0(d => d.x1).x1(d => d.x2).y0(d => d.y1).y1(d => d.y2)(d));


    const posG = svg.selectAll('.positive').data(positiveSets)
    posG.enter().append('path')
        .attr('class','positive') // "negative" color
        .attr('fill','darkblue')
        .attr("d", (d)=>d3.area().x0(d => d.x1).x1(d => d.x2).y0(d => d.y1).y1(d => d.y2)(d));


      svg.append("g")
        .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);



      // console.log(negG)

const container = d3.select("body").append("div");
container.node().appendChild(svg.node());
```

```css
#csvdata {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <h1>D3 CSV Example</h1>
```

I would like to visualize another data frame with STATE column (binary values). I want to visualize VALUE1 column that have 0 values of STATE column and VALUE1 column that have 1 values of STATE column. I can create two arrays for each.

```
let rawdata3 = rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE== 0);
let rawdata4 = rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE== 1);
```

The issue I encounter is I do not know how to update crossing points part and negative/positive area part if I want to make radial plot using two different arrays to visualize VALUE1 column depending on binary value of STATE column. Line color of VALUE1 column of rawdata3 array should be red, Line color of VALUE2 column of rawdata3 array should be blue.Line color of VALUE1 column of rawdata4 array should be green, Line color of VALUE2 column of rawdata4 array should be green.
How can I update my code so that I can make radial plot by updating crossing points part and negative/positive area part?

If green line is bigger than red line, use lighter red, else darker. If green line is bigger than blue line, use lighter blue, else darker.

What I do: I created two empty sets, i.e. negative and positive sets. I calculated crossing point of every extremity of negative and positive set, created a new set of point for area and plotted those areas. This works smoothly for different columns from same data frame(array).
TLDR: I made multiple areas. Separated my data in multiple set of contiguous “positive” or “negative” area. Then, I drew an area for each dataset.

What I expect:

I want to draw 4 lines. I would like to draw 2 lines (VALUE1 column values->red color line, VALUE2 column values->blue color line) using rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE== 0); and 2 lines (VALUE1 column values->green color line, VALUE2 column values->green color line) using rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE== 1);.

I can draw the lines. However, I cannot fill in the lines conditionally.

EDIT: I accept any other alternative solutions to this problem. I posted my attempt to show it as a help/reference.

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure, what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain your issue with more details? Then I could possibly help you.

Comment: @wasserholz I can make a radial plot and conditional filling when I get the data from an array. I do not know how to do it if I get the data from two different arrays. Please let me know which points are unclear so that I can clarify better.

Comment: Could you update your questions with a lot more details. What do you mean by getting data from two different arrays. Maybe add some pictures how the expected result should look like.

Comment: @wasserholz I just added the expected output

Comment: Thanks for updating the details. Unfortunately I still do not understand what exactly you try to achieve. Do you just want to draw multiple lines. Each line represented by a different array of points? What do you mean by crossing points? How are the arrays layed out? What exactly is the problem? Drawing the lines on the screen with d3.js or calculating the cross points? We need lot more details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @wasserholz I am having problem with calculating the cross points. Because the formula I have only works for different columns coming from same array.  I need to update it so that it works for same columns , but from different arrays

Answer (score 0):

I just found some similar questions maybe they will help you out

- [How to conditionally fill the area in radial chart correctly in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76752999/how-to-conditionally-fill-the-area-in-radial-chart-correctly-in-d3)
- [How can I properly fill the area between two line in D3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76588104/how-can-i-properly-fill-the-area-between-two-line-in-d3-js)
- [d3.js Radar Graph - filling in between lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300754/d3-js-radar-graph-filling-in-between-lines)

Comment: Thanks. If you look at my attempt, you can see that I already used those solutions. So, there is no advanced topic to help me with my question

Answer (score -1):

This is how to create a multi-line radial chart with conditional filling between two lines from different data arrays in D3.js:

First, filter the raw data into two separate arrays based on the STATE value:

```js
let data1 = rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE == 0);
let data2 = rawdata.filter(d => d.STATE == 1);
```

Then create two line generators, one for each dataset:

```js
let line1 = d3.lineRadial()
  .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime)) 
  .radius(d => y(d.VALUE1));

let line2 = d3.lineRadial()
  .angle(d => x(d.minuteTime))
  .radius(d => y(d.VALUE2));
```

Draw the lines, using different colors:

```js
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data1) 
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", line1);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data2)
  .attr("stroke", "green")
  .attr("d", line2);
```

To fill between the lines conditionally, we need to calculate the crossing points. This can be done similarly as before, but now using the separate datasets:

```js
let crossings = findCrossingPoints(data1, data2);
```

Then generate the area paths for each dataset and fill conditionally:

```js
// Fill under green line
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data2)
  .attr("fill", d => line2(d) > line1(d) ? "lightgreen" : "darkgreen")   
  .attr("d", area.radius(d => y(d.VALUE2)));

// Fill under red line   
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data1)
  .attr("fill", d => line1(d) > line2(d) ? "pink" : "red")    
  .attr("d", area.radius(d => y(d.VALUE1)));
```

This allows generating two separate lines from different data arrays, calculating crossings between them, and filling the areas conditionally based on which line is higher at each point.

Comment: Are you setting up scales separately for each dataset? Can you give working example using code snippet of Stackoverflow? I think your answer is vague because you did not use data2.

Comment: I update my answer hope it can help.

Comment: positive and negative contagious area calculation has to be also changed with crossing points. Your answer does not contain those points.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. I updated it again. Hope it will help you!